# I2C EEPROM bit-banging: Writes fine, but only if first bit is not set

Tags: i2c, eeprom

I am currently working on an I2C EEPROM project using bit-banging to drive the SDA and SCL lines.

My read function works fine but whenever I write any byte with a leading "1", I always read FF back; even if the byte has been programmed with something else before. Leading "0" is perfect. It is not my read routine; as I can see on the scope it returns FF.

I am looking for suggestions on why this might be. Is there any obvious I could miss which could cause the problem? [I cannot post the code - company confidential... :(]

Every waveform I look at meets the spec exactly. I am decoupling the EEPROM. My pull ups are 2.2k so within spec. I'm clocking at about 500 Hz in this prototype. The chip is sending ACKs to each of my bytes so it recognises them. But it just doesn't work...

I am using a Microchip [24LC256](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21203R.pdf).

Simplified writing algorithm for one byte:

```
wait
SDA low
SCL low
wait
for each bit
    if bit is set:   SDA high
    if bit is unset: SDA low
    wait
    SCL high
    wait
    wait
    SCL low
    wait
wait
SDA high 
SCL high
wait
wait
check ACK status
SDA low
SCL low
wait
return ACK status
```

Simplified reading algorithm for one byte:

```
wait
SCL low
SDA high
for each bit (8 bits)
    SCL high
    wait
    wait
    SCL low
    wait
    check and store received bit
    wait
do a NACK or ACK depending on if it is the last byte
```

Comment: Can you show us an image of your waveforms ?

Comment: I don't have a camera at work. :(

Comment: How do you know the writes are fine?

Comment: @stevenvh Because it will work for e.g. "55" or "0F", but not "AA" or "F0". I tested it with all numbers from 00 to FF and it stops past 7F, just reading all FF.

Comment: @Thomas - What I mean is that if you write "AA" it also can write "FF", so that the error is in the write operation, and that reading is OK. Do you have the EEPROM on a breadboard? If so, can you write all from "00" to "FF" to it, and read that from another controller?

Comment: I assume you've tried swapping out the part for another one?

Comment: @stevenvh It's on a PCB, SO-8 package. I have scoped the write waveform, and the data is getting there... but it's possible I've screwed up some timing somewhere causing it to misinterpret the bits. I'm just not sure how I've done it.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet Not yet, I will if all else fails but I'm not confident it's the chip.

Comment: start-bit (timing) issue?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet or pseudo code of your write and read commands. Basically anything to give us bigger context.

Comment: @MikiJ added some psuedocode for write.

Comment: @MikiJ and read, although I think this is working okay.

Comment: Is that supposed to be the start condition at the top of the code? If it is, then SCL doesn't seem to be guaranteed to be high while SDA goes low.

Comment: @Rocket AFAIK, you only need the start on the first control byte for the EEPROM. I do have that.

Comment: So addresses 0x0000 to 0x7fff are all working fine, but addresses 0x8000 to 0xffff always read back high?  Are you sure you don't really have a 128KB EEPROM?

Comment: You also have a problem in writing. At the end you do SDA_LOW then SCL_LOW which is a start. You need to do SCL_HIGH then SDL_HIGH.

Comment: You did say it is only for one byte... so my previous comment might not apply. But what worries me is that you do SDA_LOW and SCL_LOW at the beginning of the byte. If the lines really change this is a start condition and will throw off everything. You need to guarantee the starting position of the lines before you get to your write code and thus the first two lines should be removed.

Comment: @Justin - I think he's saying that writing the value 0x7F to *any* address works, but writing 0x80 to *any* address doesn't work.

Comment: It's stuff like this that makes me hate I2C.

Comment: I've got a crazy hunch. In your for each bit code, are you inadvertantly sign-extending with a shift right operation? If you are then your leading one will eventually leave you with a 0xFF after 7 shift operations.

Comment: Please post an image of the waveform. If this is worth 500 bounty, then I'm sure it's worth bringing a camera into work, or asking your boss or someone at work if they have a camera. It's pointless trying to answer this question if we can't even see the waveform.

Comment: Try implementing someone elses i2c code, e.g. the one on wikipedia..  I don't think you company will mind you posting some i2c code, it's not going to give away any secrets.

Comment: The irony, here, is the "company confidential" code.  It is valuable to them.  Everyone else here shares code that works.  What sets this company's code apart from the others is that it doesn't work.

Comment: @gbarry I finally managed to fix the code. It's only confidential because I wrote it while working there.

Comment: It's hard to imagine why a company so desperately needs to keep some I2C bit banging code confidential. There's so much of it around on the internet.

Answer (score 4):

You're reading the data after clock is low again. You'll have to do that between making the clock high and making it low. After the clock is low the slave is allowed to change the data line, not while it's high.

[image]

So reading should be like this:

```
wait
SCL low
SDA high
for each bit (8 bits)
    SCL high                      <--------
    wait
    check and store received bit  <--------
    wait
    SCL low                       <--------
    wait
    wait
do a NACK or ACK depending on if it is the last byte
```

Comment: That's a good point; I'll fix that. However, my data still shows as all-ones (FF) on my scope so my read can't be the problem... :(

Answer (score 3):

The problem in the end turned out to be that I was inadvertently sending a STOP condition under some conditions due to mangled timing. I gave up on using the scope and got out the logic analyser, and was able to fix the problem in 15 minutes as it highlighted the STOP which should not have been there. I will choose who to give the bounty to based on the most helpful answer. Thank you for all solutions.

Comment: Glad you resolved it by "verify the write timing"

Comment: I told you that this would be solved by looking at the waveform.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet I have always been looking at the waveform, but had never noticed it before.

Comment: Yes, but you did not show *us* the waveform, despite us repeatedly asking you for it. You could have had this problem solved days ago.

Comment: @Rocket - I agree. I wish I had a camera available at the time. The Tek DPO I was using had a floppy drive but no floppy. I WOULD have posted a picture if I could have.

Answer (score 2):

OK your scope proves the 1st byte coming in to the PIC is  bad so it's not the PIC read function.

Did you verify the write timing is OK at the receiving end?

Does this fail in both modes below?

```
- Byte mode sequential
- Page mode Sequential
```

The spec shows "The Most Signiﬁcant Bit (MSB) ‘b7’ is sent ﬁrst"
This also is coincident when b7=1 that the entire byte is read back as FF.
So either it is not written and only erased (fault condition) when b7=1 , or it reads back bad as FF regardless of the prior content. Since every write is a byte wide erase before write, could it still be a bad write or a bad read or the timing of the 1st byte is different.

**Suggestion:**  Verify the PTC signal during a write /read to ensure normal operation.
[image]

There is an option of using an external clock for timing the length
of an E/W cycle using PTC. 
**Have you tried to you use this?**

tE/W cycle time

- internal oscillator 7ms typ
- external clock 4 ~ 10 ms min~max

**Does it pass this criteria?**

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it could be a couple things:

1. What else is on the bus?  Could there be a bus contention with another device that is being held in reset or uninitialized?
2. Are you correctly changing the direction of the I/O pin?  If it is working fine in the output case, you could have inadvertently forgotten to change the direction of the pin to input and will always read `0xFF`.  The pin could be left as an output driving the bus while you're to read from it.
3. Do you have internal pull-ups on the pin itself and/or on the I/O lines?  Microcontrollers usually give a range of resistance and not a fixed value.  You might want to disable the pull-ups on the micro and just use the discrete ones on the bus as you can get a more precise pull-up resistance from discrete components.
4. Clock polarity - Are you sure you're measuring on the right edge/phase between the clock/data? You could be clocking out what looks great to you on the scope, but if the phase is out of line all your EEPROM will see is `0xFF`s (and would most likely return the same as it's probably an invalid command/condition).

Comment: 1. Just the EEPROM and MCU. 2. Yes, I believe I am, as the EEPROM is able to hold the SDA/SCL low. 3. There are 2.2k 5% pull ups on the board adjacent to the EEPROM.

Comment: for #2, are you sure the EEPROM is the one holding the bus low.  Does the EEPROM have any conditions in the datasheet where it will return all `0xFF`s?  See my edits above too.

Comment: #4. The EEPROM is "ACK"ing my requests and works with some words, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted this as a comment above, but my confidence in the answer has been quietly growing in the deep recesses of my mind so I'm promoting it to an answer.

I've got a crazy hunch that this is almost certainly a low level software bug relating to signedness of some variables. In your for each bit code, are you inadvertantly sign-extending with a shift right operation? If you are then your leading one will eventually leave you with a 0xFF after 7 shift operations.

Steven alluded to this in a comment, but have you witnessed the sanctity of your write operations on an osilloscope, or do you only presume that they work based on half the read backs looking good? If you haven't tried looking at the write operation of the value 0xAA, that might be a good thing to try.

If you can provide the actual code of your inner loop and associated variable declarations we might be able to spot a bug.

Comment: My writes are good; I can see this on the scope. Another weirdness: Addresses with leading MSB are okay. Only data causes issues! I think about posting the code soon.

Comment: In support of this answer: if this is C code, change all 'char' declarations to 'unsigned char' and try again.